# Maven: Writing testing library - where to place the code?

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I am writing a Java-based (built through maven) testing library. This is a library that will help other developers run JUnit tests in certain scenarios.

How do I set up the maven module for something like that? Do I place the files into `src/main` and then the module that uses my library would specify a `dependency` on my library with `<scope>test</scope>`? OR do I have to put my files into the `src/test` directory?

Also, my test library is Spring Boot based. Do I still specify:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

and then the relative starter modules if I need it for my library or, since this is a testing library, I need to do something different?

Comment: You should put it into `src/main`, and others include it with test scope (src/test should never end up in the jar file, also this way you can test your testing library). You can add your dependencies as usual.

Comment: You have to check how Maven works. The code in the final jar will include the class files from the java files under src/main/java. All the files in src/test/java are for the unit test of the library you want to write.

Comment: @heospark Yeah, that's what I thought, but wanted to ask for a sanity check. I am currently doing something wrong as my custom annotation class isn't being recognized (as if it's not on the classpath) in a separate module with a dep on my library (with scope=test).